# Запятая после "знаю" и перед "почему"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

"...не знаю(,) ли верну".

"Но она никак не может вспомнить(,) почему".

Нужна ли там запятая и почему?

Answer (score 4):

Правильно:

1) **Не знаю, верну ли.**

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным изъяснительным; в роли союза выступает вопросительная частица ЛИ.

2) Но она никак не может вспомнить **почему.**

Если придаточное предложение состоит **из одного союзного слова,** то запятая обычно не ставится.

**Примеры:**

Но так и не позвонил, и уже трудно **вспомнить почему**. [Андрей Волос. Недвижимость (2000) // «Новый Мир», 2001]

**Вариант с обособлением (интонационное выделение):**
Люди ведут себя, как животные, только не могут вспомнить ― **почему.** [Михаил Шишкин. Письмовник (2009) // «Знамя», 2010]

Но: ― Никак не могу вспомнить, **почему я им поверил**, ― жалобно пробормотал Мышкин себе под нос. [Вера Белоусова. Жил на свете рыцарь бедный (2000)]

Здесь полное придаточное предложение.